# Magento Module DHL Error After Upgrade 2.3.0 to 2.3.1

Tags: magento2.3, shipping-methods, dhl

Recently haved upgrade Magento 2.3.0 to 2.3.1
Before upgrade have create a Sample product with all data request for the methods shippings,
Weight - Price - Setting "Country inside Config" etc etc.
During this test, the APIs connection works correctly and DHL return the correct data and shipping method.

But after Upgrade, and re-create new product with all data, i received this message

```
This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us.
```

Above message is the default message when DHL is angry for some reason.
Similar message was return me when during the first test i don't have put the weight.
I had noticed and I had solved it in the first tests.

But the new product have Weight / Height / Depth and Width and more, but in any case return me error.

Also, have check log and inside the log have fount this message:

```
        <Condition>
            <ConditionCode>410301</ConditionCode>
            <ConditionData>Products not available between this origin and destination (network segment)</ConditionData>
        </Condition>
```

What is the reason ?
Who can help me ?
Thank you so much to all.